# Issue downgrading from Ubuntu 18.10 to 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04, 18.10, gvfs

I'm trying to install the updated 18.04.2 release.  I was on 18.10 but I'm clearing the drive and doing a fresh install. However, during installation I'm met with:

```sh
ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[3082]: g_u_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
```

Any help at all would be appreciated.  Thanks! :)

Comment: What was wrong with 18.10?

Comment: I don't know your error, and I'm assuming you are re-installing 18.04.2, so did you verify the write-to-thumb-drive (or install-media)?   A bit wrong can create strange unexpected results...